# 50 MHz to 64KHz frequency

Tags: vhdl

i am getting warnings like

WARNING:Xst:647 - Input  is never used. This port will be preserved and left unconnected if it belongs to a top-level block or it belongs to a sub-block and the hierarchy of this sub-block is preserved.
WARNING:Xst:647 - Input  is never used. This port will be preserved and left unconnected if it belongs to a top-level block or it belongs to a sub-block and the hierarchy of this sub-block is preserved.
WARNING:Xst:647 - Input  is never used. This port will be preserved and left unconnected if it belongs to a top-level block or it belongs to a sub-block and the hierarchy of this sub-block is preserved.
WARNING:Xst:647 - Input  is never used. This port will be preserved and left unconnected if it belongs to a top-level block or it belongs to a sub-block and the hierarchy of this sub-block is preserved.
WARNING:Xst:647 - Input  is never used. This port will be preserved and left unconnected if it belongs to a top-level block or it belongs to a sub-block and the hierarchy of this sub-block is preserved.
WARNING:Xst:1290 - Hierarchical block  is unconnected in block .
   It will be removed from the design.
WARNING:Xst:1290 - Hierarchical block  is unconnected in block .
   It will be removed from the design.
WARNING:Xst:1290 - Hierarchical block  is unconnected in block .
   It will be removed from the design.
WARNING:Xst:524 - All outputs of the instance  of the block  are unconnected in block .
   This instance will be removed from the design along with all underlying logic
WARNING:Xst:2677 - Node  of sequential type is unconnected in block .
WARNING:Xst:1710 - FF/Latch  (without init value) has a constant value of 0 in block . This FF/Latch will be trimmed during the optimization process.
WARNING:Xst:1895 - Due to other FF/Latch trimming, FF/Latch  (without init value) has a constant value of 0 in block . This FF/Latch will be trimmed during the optimization process.
WARNING:Xst:1895 - Due to other FF/Latch trimming, FF/Latch  (without init value) has a constant value of 0 in block . This FF/Latch will be trimmed during the optimization process.
WARNING:Xst:1895 - Due to other FF/Latch trimming, FF/Latch  (without init value) has a constant value of 0 in block . This FF/Latch will be trimmed during the optimization process.
WARNING:Xst:1895 - Due to other FF/Latch trimming, FF/Latch  (without init value) has a constant value of 0 in block . This FF/Latch will be trimmed during the optimization process.
WARNING:Xst:1895 - Due to other FF/Latch trimming, FF/Latch  (without init value) has a constant value of 0 in block . This FF/Latch will be trimmed during the optimization process.

```
-- ///////// 50MHz to 64KHz ///////////
    library IEEE;
    use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;
    use ieee.numeric_std.all;
    use ieee.std_logic_arith.all;
    use ieee.std_logic_unsigned.all;

    entity clk64kHz is -- input freq 50MHz and output is 64MHz
        Port (
            clk    : in  STD_LOGIC;
            reset  : in  STD_LOGIC;
            clk_out: out STD_LOGIC
        );
    end clk64kHz;

    architecture Behavioral of clk64kHz is
        signal temporal: STD_LOGIC := '0';
        signal counter : STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (8 downto 0) := "000000000";
    begin
        freq_divider: process (reset, clk) begin
            if (reset = '1') then
                temporal <= '0';
                counter  <= "000000000";
            elsif rising_edge(clk) then
                if (counter = "110000110") then -- conuter 50MHz/64KHz = 790/2 = 110000110 50% duty cycle
                    temporal <= NOT(temporal);
                    counter  <= "000000000";
                else
                    counter <= counter + 1;
                end if;
            end if;
        end process;

        clk_out <= temporal;
    end Behavioral;

    -- /////////////// time period of 10ms //////////////////
    library IEEE;
    use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;
    use IEEE.NUMERIC_STD.ALL;
    use ieee.std_logic_arith.all;
    use ieee.std_logic_unsigned.all;


    entity counter_10ms is
        Port ( clk_out : in  STD_LOGIC := '0';
               reset : in  STD_LOGIC;
               counter_out : out  STD_LOGIC_vector(9 downto 0) := "0000000000");
    end counter_10ms;


    architecture Behavioral of counter_10ms is

        signal cnt : std_logic_vector (9 downto 0) := "0000000000"; 
           -- Counter, from 0 to 640 (10msx64Khz=1010000000)
    begin

        counter: process (clk_out,reset) 
         begin
            if (reset = '1') then
                cnt <= "0000000000";
            elsif rising_edge(clk_out) then
                  if (cnt = "1010000000") then
                        cnt <= ("0000000000");
                else
                    cnt <= cnt + 1;
                end if;
            end if;
        end process;
     counter_out <= cnt;
    end Behavioral;

    --//////////////////////////////////// decoder/////////////////////////////////////////////

    library IEEE;
    use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;


    entity decoder_4to10 is
        Port ( clk_out :in std_logic;
                data_in : in  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (3 downto 0);
               data_out : out  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (9 downto 0));
    end decoder_4to10;

    architecture Behavioral of decoder_4to10 is
    -- signal clk_out : std_logic := '0';
    begin

    decoder_process : process (data_in,clk_out)
    begin

    case (data_in) is

                when "0000" => data_out <= "0001000000";
                when "0001" => data_out <= "0010000000";
                when "0010" => data_out <= "0011000000";
                when "0011" => data_out <= "0100000000";
                when "0100" => data_out <= "0101000000";
                when "0101" => data_out <= "0110000000";
                when "0110" => data_out <= "0111000000";
                when "0111" => data_out <= "1000000000";
                when "1000" => data_out <= "1001000000";
                when "1001" => data_out <= "1010000000";
                when others => data_out <= "0000000000";
    end case;
    end process decoder_process;

    end Behavioral;

    -- ////////////////// comparator ////////////////////////
    library IEEE;
    use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;


    entity comparator is
        Port ( data_in : in  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (3 downto 0);
                  reset : in    STD_LOGIC;
                  clk : in std_logic :='0';
                  pwm_out : out  STD_LOGIC);

    end comparator;

    architecture Behavioral of comparator is

    signal counter_out : std_logic_vector (9 downto 0):= "0000000000";
    -- signal data_in : std_logic_vector (3 downto 0);
    -- signal clk: std_logic :=0;

    begin

    my_process : process (clk,reset,data_in)

    begin

    if rising_edge(clk) then

          if reset ='1' then
         pwm_out <= '0';

    elsif counter_out < data_in then

    pwm_out <= '1';

    else

    pwm_out <= '0';
    end if;
          end if;
    end process;

    end Behavioral;

    -- ////////////  top module //////////////////

    library IEEE;
    use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;
    use ieee.numeric_std.all;
    use ieee.std_logic_arith.all;
    use ieee.std_logic_unsigned.all;

    entity pwm_10ms is
        Port (
                clk: in std_logic;
                reset : in  STD_LOGIC;
               data_in : in  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(3 downto 0);
               pwm_out : out  STD_LOGIC);
    end pwm_10ms;

    architecture Behavioral of pwm_10ms is

    component clk64kHz is -- input freq 50MHz and output is 64MHz
        Port (
            clk    : in  STD_LOGIC;
            reset  : in  STD_LOGIC;
            clk_out: out STD_LOGIC);
    end component;

    component counter_10ms is
        Port ( clk_out : in  STD_LOGIC := '0';
               reset : in  STD_LOGIC;
               counter_out : out  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (9 downto 0));
    end component;

    component decoder_4to10 is
        Port ( clk_out :in std_logic;
         data_in : in  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (3 downto 0);
               data_out : out  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (9 downto 0));
    end component;

    component comparator is
        Port ( data_in : in  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (3 downto 0);
                  reset : in    STD_LOGIC;
                  clk : in std_logic :='0';
                  pwm_out : out  STD_LOGIC);

    end component;

    -- signal clk :std_logic := '0';
    signal clk_out : std_logic:= '0';
    signal counter_out :std_logic_vector (9 downto 0):= "0000000000";
    signal data_out : std_logic_vector(9 downto 0) := "0000000000";
    -- signal data_in : std_logic_vector (3 downto 0) := "0000";

    begin

    clk64KHz_map    : clk64KHz PORT MAP(clk,reset,clk_out);
    counter_map     : counter_10ms PORT MAP(clk_out,reset,counter_out);
    decoder_map     : decoder_4to10 PORT MAP(clk_out,data_in,data_out);
    comparator_map  : comparator PORT MAP (data_in,reset,clk_out,pwm_out);

    end Behavioral;
    -- /////////////////////////////////////////// end of top module///////////////////////////////////
```

hello plz help me to get the correct output. I need a variable duty cycle using a decoder with rferesh period of 10 ms, using a frequency converter from 50Mhz to 64KHz. I am getting v bad warnings and errors

Comment: Could you be a little more specific about the *bad warnings and errors*?

Comment: Input <reset> is never used. This port will be preserved and left unconnected if it belongs to a top-level block or it belongs to a sub-block and the hierarchy of this sub-block is preserved.
WARNING:Xst:647 - Input <clk> is never used. This port will be preserved and left unconnected if it belongs to a top-level block or it belongs to a sub-block and the hierarchy of this sub-block is preserved.
WARNING:Xst:647 - Input <data_out> is never used. This port will be preserved and left unconnected if it belongs to a top-level block or it belongs to a sub-block

Answer (score 0):

In module comparator : The size of (data_in) and (counter_out) is not equal. In my_process they have been compared. Also it's better to assign the signal (counter_out) after (begin) statement in architecture;

In module decoder : The input (clk_out) is never used. Why did you declare it ??? just remove it.

In module pwm_10ms : Just declare signals (counter_out) and (data_out) inside the port list and remove the same signals from architecture;